# How can I access inline template as text value for GrabtheCode on button click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am looking for a functionality similar to the functionality of Grab the code button specified in this url: http://www.accuweather.com/en/free-weather-widgets/36hour.

I want to have the complete template rendered in the widget when i click on Grabthecode button with the properties implemented.

To implement that I am using a directive to change width and height of the widget and using and inline templateURL for that directive.

Grabthecode button is not the part of that directive. I am using following code to open the popup for the code.

```
.controller('iruDiscountWidgetController', ['$scope', 'ngDialog',
function($scope, ngDialog) {    
  $scope.resize = function(evt, ui) {
    $scope.w = ui.size.width;
    $scope.h = ui.size.height;

    $scope.getCode = function() {
      ngDialog.open({
        template: '<div>Copy your code:<br /><br />' +
          '<textarea rows="4" cols ="50" value="yahoo" ></textarea></div>',
        plain: true,
        scope: $scope,
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {}]
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

How can i access the same template content of GrabtheCode button that I have used as templateUrl in directive for showing on button click? Any suggestions?